# How to narrow down data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

Pardon my less than perfect title but having some issues grasping this.

So here's the manually created data. There are three fields; state, codetype, and code. The reason for this is that I am trying to join a more expansive version of this to a data frame consisting of 1.6 million rows and running into an issue of not having enough memory. My thought process is that I would greatly lower the number of rows in this table; industry.

```
state <- c(32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32)
codetype <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10)
code <- c(522,523,524,532,533,534,544,545,546,551,552,552,561,562,563,571,572,573,574)



industry = data.frame(state,codetype,code)
```

The desired result would be a two fold operation. First, I would shorten down the six digit codes to 2. That is done via.

```
industry<-industry %>% mutate(twodigit = substr(code,1,2).
```

This would produce a fifth column, twodigit. At present, there are 19 values. But only 7 unique values of twodigit; 52,53,54,55,56,57. How would tell it remove all nonunique values of the two digit?

Comment: Do you need `industry %>% distinct(twodigit, .keep_all = TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun, write this as an answer. Yes, it worked and thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `distinct` and specify the `.keep_all` as TRUE to get the entire columns

```
library(dplyr)
industry %>%
   distinct(twodigit, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Another option would be to use `duplicated` in `filter`

```
industry %>%
    filter(!duplicated(twodigit))
```

---

To make this more efficient, perhaps use `data.table` approaches

```
library(data.table)
setDT(industry)[!duplicated(substr(code, 1, 2))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using`unique()` approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)

state <- c(32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32)
codetype <- c(10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10)
code <- c(522,523,524,532,533,534,544,545,546,551,552,552,561,562,563,571,572,573,574)
industry = data.frame(state,codetype,code)
industry<-industry %>% mutate(twodigit = substr(code,1,2))


unique(industry$twodigit) %>%
    map_dfr(~filter(industry, twodigit == .x)[1, ])
#>   state codetype code twodigit
#> 1    32       10  522       52
#> 2    32       10  532       53
#> 3    32       10  544       54
#> 4    32       10  551       55
#> 5    32       10  561       56
#> 6    32       10  571       57
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>